# Terraform cannot concat NULL values

Tags: terraform

My goal is to achieve below URLs using Terraform.

```
ec2-environment1-region1.special.myurl.com
ec2-environment2-region1.special.myurl.com
ec2-environment3-region1.special.myurl.com
ec2-environment4-region2.myurl.com
ec2-environment5-region3.myurl.com
```

I used **join** function. Below is the code.

```
join(".", ["ec2-${var.env}-${var.region}", var.region == "region1" ? "special" : null, "myurl.com"])
```

So when I pass `var.region` `==` `"region1"` the URL is correctly created as below:

```
ec2-environment1-region1.special.myurl.com
```

But if I pass something else than `region1` to `var.region` it gives the below error.

```
Invalid value for "lists" parameter: element 1 is null; cannot concatenate null values.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform's compact function deletes null values from a list ([docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/compact)), so you may use it to obtain a null-free list before joining.

```
join(".", compact(["ec2-${var.env}-${var.region}", var.region == "region1" ? "special" : null, "myurl.com"]))
```